# not able to add subnet or security group to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-vpc

When I try to add security group or subnet id to the lambda, this error is returned in terraform apply

Here is the error

Inappropriate value for attribute "subnet_ids": set of string required.
Inappropriate value for attribute "security_group_ids": set of string required.

Here is the code

Here is the VPC config that I am trying to add to lambda module

```
vpc_config {
   subnet_ids         = var.subnet_ids
   security_group_ids = var.security_group_ids
   }
```

These are the values trying to pass from main

```
variable "subnet_ids" {
   default     = "subnet-05xxxxxxxxx"
  }
variable "security_group_ids" {
   default     = "sg-020xxxxxxxxx"
  }`
```

Terraform is throwing error

Answer (score 1):

Both of those variables are a single string. The attributes you are trying to set expect a "set of strings", just like the error message says. You need to wrap the single values in brackets to make them a set.

```
vpc_config {
   subnet_ids         = [var.subnet_ids]
   security_group_ids = [var.security_group_ids]
}
```

---

Or, fix it in the variables:

```
variable "subnet_ids" {
   type     = set(string)
   default  = ["subnet-05xxxxxxxxx"]
}

variable "security_group_ids" {
   type     = set(string)
   default  = ["sg-020xxxxxxxxx"]
}
```

And then reference them like you were:

```
vpc_config {
   subnet_ids         = var.subnet_ids
   security_group_ids = var.security_group_ids
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, this has solved the problem. I just need to apply correct IAM role/policy to lambda for this subnet and SG to be attached to lambda. Thanks once again.